# RSS Feed showing only 50 items

Tags: rss

I created Rss Feed following https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/setting-up-rss-feeds.html. It returns only 50 items no matter where i point it to in the content tree(including Home), there are more than 100 content items.

I even tried changing limit value to 100 in config file.

-->
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF ITEMS IN FEED
The maximum number of items to include in the client feed.
Default value: 50

```
<setting name="ClientFeeds.MaximumItemsInFeed" value="50"/>
```

-->

But still, it didn't work. 
Is something am missing? Please help and give me thoughts on achieving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change setting <setting name="Feeds.MaximumItemsInFeed" value="50" /> ?

Comment: @x3mxray Yey! that worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

By default, two settings in the `sitecore.config` file limit the maximum number of items that can appear in an RSS feed.

- **Feeds.MaximumItemsInFeed**  - limits the number of items that can appear in a public RSS feed.
- **ClientFeeds.MaximumItemsInFeed** - limits the number of items that can appear in a client RSS feed (for CMS users, such as workflow notification).